# Get Date Instance and Display it on Page Load

Tags: javascript, date, knockout.js

I want to display current `date` on my page load in textbox.

I have tried following and work fine :

```
var startdate=new Date();
console.log(startdate);
console.log(startdate.getDate());
console.log(startdate.getMonth()+1);
console.log(startdate.getFullYear());
```

gives me output as :

```
Mon May 05 2014 10:31:39 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
5 //date
5 //month 
2014 //year
```

but i want month `05` date as also `05` means with `prefixed 0` if date or month is in `single digit`.

and I also want that if I ll change the value of this textbox to other date in `MM/DD/YYYY` format then it's effect should be shown on other textbox, In other textbox I want to show display date of after one week (+7 days in textbox date).
Suppose I enter date `05/05/2014` then in other textbox (i.e. end date) have date like `05/12/2014`.

So how to do so I don't know, so any guidance on it please.
I am using `knockout js`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like below

```
var startdate = new Date();
var formatedDate = ('0'+ (startdate.getMonth() +1)).slice(-2) + "/" + 
               ('0'+ startdate.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/"  +
               startdate.getFullYear();


var endDate = startdate;
endDate.setDate(endDate.getDate() + 7);
var formatedEndDate = ('0'+ (endDate.getMonth() +1)).slice(-2) + "/" + 
               ('0'+ endDate.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/"  +
               endDate.getFullYear();
```

Comment: Sir, I want end date on base of start date textbox value. means when I edit start date value then it automatically change the end date value..

Comment: Shall it will make change automatically on in end date when I ll change start date ? Or I have to use `ko.computed` and in that I ll write this code ?

Comment: Yes you have written separate method either in `ko.computed`.    *You mean automatically changing the endDate based on startDate?  if this is the case I would suggest you to look into [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and fyi that knockout also use one*

Comment: Sir it is working fine, but shall it will get date data from `05/06/2014` from textbox ?Suppose I ll add that data in textbox then how it will get date,month and year ? because right now we are using new Date()'s instance to get date in end date also, so any idea on it ?

Comment: @user3145373ツ I think this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/uLLnC/1/) will solve your problem.  However consider using datepickers.

Comment: Thank You sir, it works great, I have made some required changes and work totally great. Thanks Pravin bhai.

Comment: @user3145373ツ Glad to help you.  BTW: you can call me by my name no need of prefixes  :)